# Unable to parse some content using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've tried to create a script using `re` module in combination with `python` to parse `address`, `phone` and `email` from a long string with newlines in between. There are two sets of container in there. When I run my script, It gives me the result of first container let alone unwanted portion in it. I don't know the way I've tried below is of any valid attempt at all!! Any help will be highly appreciated.

I've tried with:

```
import re

rstr = """
    Address The Westshore Grand,
    A Tribute Portfolio Hotel, Tampa

    Telephone 52 70 90 00
    E-mail info.suchona@gmail.com


    Address hotels near 1255 north palm ave 
    sarasota florida

    Telephone 62 40 80 00
    E-mail info.niit@hotmail.com
"""
address = re.findall(r'(Address.+)',rstr)[0].strip()
phone = re.findall(r'(Telephone.+)',rstr)[0].strip()
email = re.findall(r'(E-mail.+)',rstr)[0].strip()
print(f'{address}\n{phone}\n{email}')
```

Result I'm having:

```
Address The Westshore Grand,
Telephone 52 70 90 00
E-mail info.suchona@gmail.com
```

What I wish to have:

```
The Westshore Grand, A Tribute Portfolio Hotel, Tampa
52 70 90 00
info.suchona@gmail.com

hotels near 1255 north palm ave sarasota florida
62 40 80 00
info.niit@hotmail.com
```

Although I know It can be achieved through string manipulation, I like to follow the `regex` way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to match newlines: use `re.DOTALL`
- You also want to grab everything between `address` and `telephone` but to be non greedy `.+?`
- In addition you want to store that as a group, so wrap in `()`
- Replace all whitespace with just a space: `re.sub`

The result

```
addresses = [re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', addr) 
             for addr in re.findall(r'Address (.+?)Telephone', rstr, re.DOTALL)]
```

outputs

```
['The Westshore Grand, A Tribute Portfolio Hotel, Tampa',
 'hotels near 1255 north palm ave sarasota florida']
```

also do

```
phones = re.findall(r'Telephone\s*(.+)\s*', rstr)
emails = re.findall(r'E-mail\s*(.+)\s*', rstr)
```

Then you can loop over them:

```
for addr, phone, email in zip(addresses, phones, emails):
    print(addr, phone, email, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The Westshore Grand, A Tribute Portfolio Hotel, Tampa 
52 70 90 00
info.suchona@gmail.com

hotels near 1255 north palm ave sarasota florida 
62 40 80 00
info.niit@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex to get your address.

```
address = re.findall(r'(?<=Address).*?(?=Telephone)',rstr, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

**Demo:**

```
address = re.findall(r'(?<=Address).*?(?=Telephone)',rstr, flags=re.DOTALL)
phone = re.findall(r'(Telephone.+)',rstr)
email = re.findall(r'(E-mail.+)',rstr)
for i in zip(address, phone, email):
    print('{address}\n{phone}\n{email}'.format(address=i[0].strip(), phone=i[1].strip(), email=i[2].strip()))
    print( "-----" )
```

**Output:**

```
The Westshore Grand,
    A Tribute Portfolio Hotel, Tampa
Telephone 52 70 90 00
E-mail info.suchona@gmail.com
-----
hotels near 1255 north palm ave 
    sarasota florida
Telephone 62 40 80 00
E-mail info.niit@hotmail.com
-----
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your RegEx capture group surround only what you want. And `re.findall()` returns all occurrences of the matched RegEx pattern, so you could simply loop through them like so (assuming all three information are always there):

```
address = re.findall(r'Address(.+?)\n\n', rstr, flags=re.S)
phone = re.findall(r'Telephone(.+)', rstr)
email = re.findall(r'E-mail(.+)', rstr)

for i in range(len(address)):
    print('\n'.join([
        re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', address[i].strip()),
        phone[i].strip(),
        email[i].strip()
    ]))
```

Output:

```
The Westshore Grand, A Tribute Portfolio Hotel, Tampa
52 70 90 00
info.suchona@gmail.com

hotels near 1255 north palm ave sarasota florida
62 40 80 00
info.niit@hotmail.com
```